# How do I change a ng-src on another img with ng-click?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

*I updated the plunkr and the code to better represent my localhost version. The Angularjs version was not the problem despite fixing the previous plunkr. *

First, let me say I am really struggling with Angularjs but I'm determined to learn it. I'm a designer, not a brick-layer (forgive the Star Trek reference).

I'm building a prototype where clicking on a small thumbnail to the left loads a larger version to the right. I'm using ng-click on the image to pass the unique "current" ID. Clicking doesn't affect the large image ng-src. I tried various permutations and don't see what I could be doing wrong.

*New info: I am using ng-repeat to iterate through a list of images. I try to pass each image url through ng-click but that seems to be where it gets lost. *

http://plnkr.co/edit/vYiykI7dfMKd34ZmS13N?p=preview

The app/controller:

```
    <script>
    var app = angular.module('pageApp', []);
      app.controller('imgCtrl', function($scope) {
        $scope.current = '7078/7250439172_72562c8e45_k';
    });
    </script>
```

The html wth thumbnail and large image:

```
    <div class="container">
  <div class="row" ng-app="pageApp" ng-controller="imgCtrl">
    <div class="col-xs-3">
      <ul class="list-group sm-img">
        <li class="list-group-item text-center" ng-repeat="n in ['7078/7250439172_72562c8e45_k', '7087/7250440014_a32980508e_k', '7225/7250440766_8db45aa277_h']">
          <img class="img-responsive" src="https://farm8.staticflickr.com/{{n}}.jpg" ng-click="current='{{n}}'" /><span>{{current}}</span>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-9">
      <img class="img-responsive" ng-src="https://farm8.staticflickr.com/{{ current }}.jpg" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: in your plunkr you're including Angular 2.0. Wouldnt start with that since it's still alpha and is absolutely different from the angular you're talking about. And despite of just starting out, you should read this article (no. 2 refers to your case) http://www.toptal.com/angular-js/top-18-most-common-angularjs-developer-mistakes and john papas style guide https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide

Comment: I didn't notice I had included Angular 2.0 in plunkr. But my localhost code was using v1.3.16. I created a simplified version on plunkr and was satisfied that it also wasn't working. My localhost code is probably too complex to post on plunkr but the problem doesn't seem to be the version even after updating to 1.4.8.

Comment: Have you solved your problem? If not, check to see if your AngularJS can add `{{1+1}}`.

Comment: No, problem not solved yet. Sorry to have that red-herring Angular version. I think this is related to scope. I don't understand scope or how to determine what's in or out of scope.

Comment: I have determined that within the left panel the {{ current }} evaluates correctly and I can see it in the browser inspector. However, further down  in the right panel it shows in the inspector as "{{current}}". I will try to show my more complex code involving ng-repeat in plunkr and update this question. BTW, {{1+1}} works.

Answer (score 0):

Try to create function in controller an execute it from ng-click

```
$scope.changeImg = function (c) {
    $scope.current=c;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem quite funny: you are loading Angular2 version however using Angular1.x syntax and code. Load correct library version, for example 1.4.8, and everything will start working properly:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.8/angular.js"></script>
```

Demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/0efkCT9wwEaWfK0nR6su?p=info

Answer (score 0):

It is working now. http://plnkr.co/edit/nmqDqcmtyTq479wZWsuR?p=preview
you are using angular 2 which has much more different than angular 1 (1.4)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="pageApp">

 <head>
 <link data-require="bootstrap@3.3.5" data-semver="3.3.5" rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<link data-require="bootstrap@3.3.5" data-semver="3.3.5" rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootswatch/3.3.5/cosmo/bootstrap.min.css" />
<link data-require="bootstrap@3.3.5" data-semver="3.3.5" rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
<script data-require="bootstrap@3.3.5" data-semver="3.3.5" src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.0/angular.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
<script src="script.js"></script>
   <script>
          var app = angular.module('pageApp', []);
      app.controller('imgCtrl', function($scope) {
        $scope.current = '7078/7250439172_72562c8e45_k';
    });
    </script>
  </head>

 <body>
<div class="container">

  <div class="row"  ng-controller="imgCtrl">
    <div class="col-xs-3">
      <img class="img-responsive" src="https://farm8.staticflickr.com/7078/7250439172_72562c8e45_k.jpg" ng-click="current='7078/7250439172_72562c8e45_k'" />
      <img class="img-responsive" src="https://farm8.staticflickr.com/7087/7250440014_a32980508e_k.jpg"  ng-click="current='7087/7250440014_a32980508e_k'" />
      <img class="img-responsive" src="https://farm8.staticflickr.com/7225/7250440766_8db45aa277_h.jpg" ng-click="current='7225/7250440766_8db45aa277_h'"/>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-9">
      <img class="img-responsive" ng-src="https://farm8.staticflickr.com/{{ current }}.jpg" />
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>

  </body>
</html>
```